# How to query data from JSON Column with Object Array

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

Assuming I have below table structure:

[image]

And `address_collection` has a value of this per table row entry:

[image]

How would I be able to query a specific json object from the array based on an `address_uid` assigned to `user_id`?

`JSON_EXTRACT()` and its `->` alias doesn't work (returns null) because as I understand, it only works on a single JSON Object.

Example:

```
SELECT
    u.*
FROM
    user u
WHERE
    u.user_id = 1
AND
    u.address_collection->"$.address_uid" = "a83b662f-60de-4d3d-ab05-43b0746fb2a2";
```

Above example yields no result due to `u.address_collection->"$.address_uid" = "a83b662f-60de-4d3d-ab05-43b0746fb2a2";`

Modifying that line to `u.address_collection->"$[0].address_uid" = "a83b662f-60de-4d3d-ab05-43b0746fb2a2";` doesn't work either as the result of the left part returns a collection of `address_uid` from the object array instead of searching it.

Comment: You want to search inside a single cell of json array data?

Comment: Provide table structure as code-formatted CREATE TABLE. Provide a value as formatted text. Provide desired output for this data. Specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: @Thejas basically, I want to get a specific object from the json array inside the json column